# Use data gotten from one table to get data from another data

Tags: laravel, model, eloquent, relationship

I have three tables

Job Model

```
+---------------------------+
| id |        name          |
+---------------------------+
| 1  |     web design       |
+---------------------------+
| 2  |  desktop development |
+---------------------------+
```

Applicant Model

```
+----------------------------------------------------------+
|  id  |  job_id  |  user_id  |           desc             |
+----------------------------------------------------------+
|   1  |     2    |      1    |  I am an expert developer  |
+----------------------------------------------------------+
|   2  |     2    |      2    |         I am good          |
+----------------------------------------------------------+
```

User Model

```
+----------------+
|  id  |   name  |
+----------------+
|   1  |   john  |
+----------------+
|   2  |  steve  |
+----------------+
```

Using eloquent laravel,
How do I get applicants with `job_id` "2" and their user name together.
Tried a lot but unfortunately to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

You would use a query something like this:

```
$jobs = Job::where('id', 2)
    ->join('applicants', 'jobs.id', '=', 'applicants.job_id')
    ->join('users', 'applicants.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
    ->select(['user.name', 'job.name', 'applicant.desc'])
    ->get();
```

You will have to change it to your requirements but should about what you need.

You can get more info here:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries

Hope that helps